# I want to replace an URL in Google Sheets as a personalized hyperlink in my Google Dcs body

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a link in one of the Google Sheets cells like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQCKB.png) and I know how to attach it to the Google Docs body through the following steps:

```
const body = doc.getBody();
body.replaceText('{{MyURL}}',row[number]
```

This gives me the result you can watch [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAN8S.png) but I would like to have this result instead ([watch here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVR5u.png))

So, how can I do this? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: this may be better asked on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function insertHyperlink() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('Insert Doc ID here');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var text = "Google Link";
  var url = "https://www.google.com/";
  body.replaceText('{{MyURL}}', text); //replace text with hyperlink label
  var foundElement = body.findText(text); //find the hyperlink label
  var foundText = foundElement.getElement().asText(); 
  var start = foundElement.getStartOffset(); 
  var end = foundElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();
  foundText.setLinkUrl(start, end, url)
}
```

### References:

- [setLinkUrl(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setlinkurlstartoffset,-endoffsetinclusive,-url)
- [findText(searchPattern)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findtextsearchpattern)

[image]